# Distinct when using 'IN' Clause

Tags: oracle11g

```
SELECT * 
FROM XYZ 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('A', 'B', 'C');
```

OUTPUT:

```
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
```

How to distinct values when using "in" clause?

Comment: you will need a subquery if you want to return all columns. Does the table have a primary key? Can you give more info on your table?

Comment: `select distinct ...`?

Answer (score 0):

The query you have written is producing the correct result.

When you execute SQL :

```
select * 
from XYZ 
where COLUMN_NAME IN ('A', 'B', 'C');
```

that means you say, select all the records from the table XYZ where column_name is A,B and C. So in this case your table is having 9 rows with all column name as A, so the result is.

If you want distinct result set then you need to use.

```
select distinct * 
from XYZ 
where COLUMN_NAME IN ('A', 'B', 'C') ;
```